# Dell Inspiron 7567 doesn't detect headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-inspiron

I bought Dell 7567 a week ago.
It's a very great laptop but when plugging in my headphone it ignores it and detects it only when I restart (windows 10).
Solutions that didn't work:

- I reinstalled the drivers.
- Switched from "Realtek Audio" to "High definition audio device"
- I even used my service tag & it didn't show any problems (while testing it ignored the headphones as well).
- I tested with Ubuntu & the headphones worked fine.

Could anyone help? It's not a big problem but it's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the Dell site to download the latest sound card that compatible with Windows 10.

Then try the following steps:

1. Go to "Control Panel".
2. Click on "Sound".
3. Make sure you are on the "Playback" tab.
4. Click on the device you are trying to fix.
5. Now click the "Configure" button and follow the prompts. (Be sure you also click the "Test" button.)
6. Once that is complete, click the "Properties" button.
7. When you are done with your changes, in "Properties", click "Apply" and then "OK".
8. Then click "OK", again, on the main "Sound window".

Answer (score 0):

- I tried the solution above (by @Karen Hu) & it didn't work for me at least.
- However [DriverBooster](https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php) did it well and even updated 14 other drivers that I 
  recently installed from dell or with windows update.